# How can I make date fields come out like dropdown menus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Is there a helper that can turn the datetime fields into select fields? I saw this in a couple of Railscast episodes. My date fields come out like input fields now.

Comment: I assume you are referring to simple HTML calendar components. Most of the ones I have seen have a drop-down input field separated for Month, Day, Hour, Minute, or something like that. The very fancy ones, often paid for, may offer more iPhone-like scrollable images and the like. You may want to clarify your question though, it's a little unclear exactly what you driving for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.date_select :field_name %>
<%= f.datetime_select :field_name %>
```

Those will create select menos if that is what you mean by 'select fields'